# Implementing a mergesort without using an additional array?

Tags: algorithm, mergesort

I've read a lot about mergesort recently and I wonder if there is a way to do a mergesort without using at least one additional array. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) it is indeed possible, but might not yield any performance gain:

> Sorting in-place is possible (e.g., using lists rather than arrays) but is very complicated, and will offer little performance gains in practice, even if the algorithm runs in O(*n* log *n*) time. In these cases, algorithms like heapsort usually offer comparable speed, and are far less complex. Additionally, unlike the standard merge sort, in-place merge sort is not a stable sort. In the case of linked lists the algorithm does not use more space than that the already used by the list representation, but the O(log(*k*)) used for the recursion trace. Some would argue that sorting a linked list is not in place because even though you are sorting in the given data structure, the data structure inherently has O(*n*) extra data you are manipulating (e.g., the links in the list).

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, it is. [This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.22.8523) describes an in-place merge sort:

> Two in-place variants of the classical mergesort algorithm are analysed in detail. The first, straightforward variant performs at most N log 2 N + O(N ) comparisons and 3N log 2 N + O(N ) moves to sort N elements. The second, more advanced variant requires at most N log 2 N + O(N ) comparisons and "N log 2 N moves, for any fixed " ? 0 and any N ? N ("). In theory, the second one is superior to advanced versions of heapsort. In practice, due to the overhead in the index manipulation, our fastest in-place mergesort behaves still about 50 per cent slower than the bottom-up heapsort. However, our implementations are practical compared to mergesort algorithms based on in-place merging.

Jyrki Katajainen, Tomi Pasanen, Jukka Teuhola, "Practical In-Place Mergesort" (1996).

Comment: Not going to summarize the paper here, I haven't read it. But I added in the abstract and reference, which should help follow any dead link trails.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Java implementation

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void iterativeMergeSort(T[] seed) {

    for (int i = 1; i <seed.length; i=i+i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < seed.length - i; j = j + i+i)
        {
            inPlaceMerge(seed, j, j + i-1, Math.min(j+i + i -1, seed.length -1));
        }
    }       
}
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>  void inPlaceMerge(T[] collection, int low, int mid, int high) {
    int left = low;
    int right = mid + 1;

    if(collection[mid].equals(collection[right])) {
        return ;//Skip the merge if required
    }
    while (left <= mid && right <= high) {          
        // Select from left:  no change, just advance left
        if (collection[left].compareTo(collection[right]) <= 0) {
            left ++;
        } else { // Select from right:  rotate [left..right] and correct
            T tmp = collection[right]; // Will move to [left]
            rotateRight(collection, left, right - left);
            collection[left] = tmp;
            // EVERYTHING has moved up by one
            left ++; right ++; mid ++;
        }
    }       
}
```

Here is the unit test

```
private Integer[] seed;

@Before
public void doBeforeEachTestCase() {
    this.seed = new Integer[]{4,2,3,1,5,8,7,6};
}
@Test
public void iterativeMergeSortFirstTest() {
    ArrayUtils.<Integer>iterativeMergeSort(seed);
    Integer[] result = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    assertThat(seed, equalTo(result));  
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code for `rotateRight` method?

Answer (score -3):

No, you'll always need an extra data structure to merge the sorted elements to. If not you'll just be overwriting the stuff you already sorted.

Comment: For the record, it is very hard to prove a negative.